# C++ moving object on heap into local object in a well defined manner

Tags: c++, c++-concepts

Is it possible to move a moveable heap instance into a local object? I have the example code below:

```
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>
#include <concepts>
#include <string>

template<std::move_constructible T>
struct LazyGuard
{
    T value;
    LazyGuard(T* const ptr) : value(std::move(*ptr)) { }
};

template <std::move_constructible T>
inline T&& MakeLocal(T* ptr)
{
    return std::move(*ptr);
}

int main()
{
    LazyGuard<std::string> guard(new std::string("Will be using with 'Socket* TCPSocket::FromAddress' kind of constructors"));
    // Or another way
    std::string local2 = MakeLocal(new std::string("similar thing"));
    // Or another way
    std::string local3(MakeLocal(new std::string("similar thing")));
    return 0;
}
```

What I want to know is:

- Can we guarantee the move constructor (or move assignment operator) will be called?
- Is the code well-defined, or can it be made well-defined?

I know it is possible to use smart pointers, but it is not what I am asking here.

Update: To fix the leak problem I am adding delete in the guard constructor so the improved example below. I could not find a way to do this with "MakeLocal" example is this possible in any way?:

```
template<std::move_constructible T>
struct LazyGuard
{
    T value;
    LazyGuard(T* const ptr) : value(std::move(*ptr)) { delete ptr; }
};


int main()
{
    LazyGuard<std::string> guard(new std::string("Will be using with 'Socket* TCPSocket::FromAddress' kind of constructors"));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: All of those moved-from instances you `new` still leak.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux fixed the leak problem by introducing delete in the constructor,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can we guarantee the move constructor (or move assignment operator) will be called?

Yes

Heap vs stack only "means" anything as far as memory allocation/deallocation is concerned. Apart from that, they are effectively indistinguishable. An object is an object with all that this entails no matter where its memory is located.

There is no distinction between moving objects from the heap to the heap, from the stack to the stack, from the heap to the stack, or from the stack to the heap.

In short: Yes, you can safely move-construct or move-assign a stack-based object from an instance living on the heap.

> Is the code well-defined, or can it be made well-defined?

It is *well-defined* , but not well-behaved.

Note that I said move-**construct**. This does NOT destroy the object on the heap, just moves its *content* to the stack. You still need to destroy the original object.

As it stands, your code is leaking a bunch of memory.

**Edit**: The updated constructor of `LazyGuard` will *work* without leaking memory. However, a constructor taking ownership of a raw pointer is very, very bad design.

`LazyGuard` should really be written like this:

```
template<std::move_constructible T>
struct LazyGuard
{
    T value;
    LazyGuard(T v) : value(std::move(v)) {}
};
```

Where its initializer comes from is none of its business, that's a problem for where it is used.

Comment: Can you update the example for using it with pointers as well. I want to use it with pointer type, so will I be calling like this: LazyGuard<string>(* new string("")) ? Also deleting it will be again an issue. I want to have a local object from pointer that will be cleaned with the scope,

Comment: @Abdurrahim What's wrong with `LazyGuard<string>("some string")`?

Comment: No issue but I am not using it with string but I am gonna use it with named constructors like "LazyGuard<Socket> socket (TCPSocket::FromAddress(address, port));. I just wanted to check if I can skip unique_ptr with concepts,

Comment: With the change, `new` can no longer be used in the construction of `guard`. (but that is much cleaner to simply construct a new object rather than allocating for one)

Comment: @Abdurrahim That will never work no matter what you do, `FromAddress` almost certainly returns a subclass of `Socket` you cannot move a subclass to its parrent like that.

Comment: Then the answer is no. Move constructor is not well defined in such cases and it will not work in the standard? Or can we make it check in compile time with concepts like is this not base class etc. Or maybe if we check the object has virtual destructor in the concept then will it work?